# Real JSON nested dictionaries Get dict with Python / pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary, nested

i stuck in a dirty nested json.
Anyone can find the way to normalize de dic inside "extra_data" > "additional_value" ?
or just take in a column the new_value integer from inside :sudor:

```
{"old_value":9500,"new_value":8800,"currency":"ARS","type":"payment_amount"}
```

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "object_id": "23843009595880561",
            "event_time": "2019-08-08T13:38:44+0000",
            "extra_data": '{"old_value":"BID_CAP","new_value":"BID_CAP","additional_value": {"old_value":9500,"new_value":8800,"currency":"ARS","type":"payment_amount"}, "adset_minimum_return_on_ad_spend":{"old_value":null,"new_value":null},"type":"bid_type"}',
            "object_name": "LK 17 - 50 - Eventos PX - 1%",
        },
        # ....
    ]
}
```

Comment: maybe use module `json` to convert it - like `json.loads( item["data"][0]["extra_data"] )`. And if you have more elements then use it `for`-loop

Answer (score 0):

You can "rehydrate" that `extra_data` (which seems like a string of JSON) back to a Python dict easily enough:

```
import json

my_data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "object_id": "23843009595880561",
            "event_time": "2019-08-08T13:38:44+0000",
            "extra_data": '{"old_value":"BID_CAP","new_value":"BID_CAP","additional_value": {"old_value":9500,"new_value":8800,"currency":"ARS","type":"payment_amount"}, "adset_minimum_return_on_ad_spend":{"old_value":null,"new_value":null},"type":"bid_type"}',
            "object_name": "LK 17 - 50 - Eventos PX - 1%",
        },
        # ....
    ]
}

for object in my_data["data"]:
    object["extra_data"] = json.loads(object["extra_data"])

print(json.dumps(object, indent=2))
```

This outputs (just so we can see what we're working with)

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "object_id": "23843009595880561",
      "event_time": "2019-08-08T13:38:44+0000",
      "extra_data": {
        "old_value": "BID_CAP",
        "new_value": "BID_CAP",
        "additional_value": {
          "old_value": 9500,
          "new_value": 8800,
          "currency": "ARS",
          "type": "payment_amount"
        },
        "adset_minimum_return_on_ad_spend": {
          "old_value": null,
          "new_value": null
        },
        "type": "bid_type"
      },
      "object_name": "LK 17 - 50 - Eventos PX - 1%"
    }
  ]
}
```

so now you can iterate over those objects (of which there is only one in your example, but the point stands):

```
for object in my_data["data"]:
    object["extra_data"] = json.loads(object["extra_data"])
    print(object["extra_data"]["additional_value"])
```

This prints out

```
{'old_value': 9500, 'new_value': 8800, 'currency': 'ARS', 'type': 'payment_amount'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use module `json` to convert it.

```
items = {
    "data": [
        {
            "object_id": "23843009595880561",
            "event_time": "2019-08-08T13:38:44+0000",
            "extra_data": '{"old_value":"BID_CAP","new_value":"BID_CAP","additional_value": {"old_value":9500,"new_value":8800,"currency":"ARS","type":"payment_amount"}, "adset_minimum_return_on_ad_spend":{"old_value":null,"new_value":null},"type":"bid_type"}',
            "object_name": "LK 17 - 50 - Eventos PX - 1%",
        },
    ]
}

import json

converted = json.loads(items['data'][0]["extra_data"])

print(converted["additional_value"])
```

You could also use `for`-loop to convert all `"extra_data"`

```
items = {
    "data": [
        {
            "object_id": "23843009595880561",
            "event_time": "2019-08-08T13:38:44+0000",
            "extra_data": '{"old_value":"BID_CAP","new_value":"BID_CAP","additional_value": {"old_value":9500,"new_value":8800,"currency":"ARS","type":"payment_amount"}, "adset_minimum_return_on_ad_spend":{"old_value":null,"new_value":null},"type":"bid_type"}',
            "object_name": "LK 17 - 50 - Eventos PX - 1%",
        },
        {
            "object_id": "23843009595880561",
            "event_time": "2019-08-08T13:38:44+0000",
            "extra_data": '{"old_value":"BID_CAP","new_value":"BID_CAP","additional_value": {"old_value":9500,"new_value":8800,"currency":"ARS","type":"payment_amount"}, "adset_minimum_return_on_ad_spend":{"old_value":null,"new_value":null},"type":"bid_type"}',
            "object_name": "LK 17 - 50 - Eventos PX - 1%",
        },
    ]
}

import json

# convert all "extra_data"

for element in items["data"]:
    element["extra_data"] = json.loads( element["extra_data"] )
    
# display all "extra_data"

for element in items["data"]:
    print(element["extra_data"]["additional_value"])
```